# How to show that $S(t)$ if a uniformly continuous group of bounded operators?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, operator-theory

Let $X$ be the space of all continuous functions $u \in C(\mathbb R)$ where $$\lim_{t \to \pm \infty}u(t)=0$$ provided with the $\sup$-norm $$\vert\vert u \vert\vert_\infty=\sup_{t \in \mathbb R}\vert u(t)\vert.$$
Now let $g \in C(\mathbb R)$ a bounded, continuous function. For $t \in \mathbb R$ define $$S(t): X \to X,   \\ u \mapsto  S(t)u :=\exp(tg)u$$
where $S(t)$ is the multiplication operator of the function $\exp(tg)$.

How can I show that $(S(t))_{t \in \mathbb R}$ is a uniformly continuous group of bounded operators?

Comment: Do I understand it right, that $\bigl(S(t)u\bigr)(s) = e^{t\cdot g(s)}u(s)$?

Comment: By the way, the standard notation is $X = C_0(\mathbb{R})$. Only there are some people who use $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ to denote $C_c(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Yes that is right I guess. Ok will adjust next time, thanks.

Comment: From the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0-semigroup) there are 4 things you need to show. Which are you having trouble with?

Comment: Kind of all of them. For example, why should $S(t)u(0)=id$?

Comment: That's not what you need to show. You need to show $S(0) = \operatorname{id}_X$, i.e. $S(0)u = u$ for all $u \in X$.

Comment: Well that kind of answers most of my questions..Thanks!